# Vim Autoaligment in VscodeVim

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Using vscodevim, how to use autoaligment using `=` like Vim do? so for example :

```
.wrapper-box {
        // line is out of tab. 
        .box {
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
}
```

In vim, i can select the `.wrapper-box` and then hit the `=` and the line autoalignment / autoindent. How to use this keybinding in VscodeVim?

Answer (score 0):

```
`"vim.otherModesKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                "="
            ],
            "after": [],
            "commands": [
                {
                    "command": "editor.action.reindentlines",
                    "args": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
`
```

Sorry, has answered.